# MySQL error connecting when creating a user using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a php form that for registering the user and store their information in MySQL table. Here is the error following that a PHP code and the MySQL table.

> Warning: mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /hsphere/local/home/khalidalomar/khalidalomar.com/talent/added.php on line 22 Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /hsphere/local/home/khalidalomar/khalidalomar.com/talent/added.php on line 22 Invalid query: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Here is my PHP code

```
include("connect.php");

// Talent table
$t_username = strip_tags(substr($_POST['t_username'],0,32));
$t_password = strip_tags(substr($_POST['t_password'],0,32));
$t_fname = strip_tags(substr($_POST['t_fname'],0,32));
$t_lname = strip_tags(substr($_POST['t_lname'],0,32));
$t_cname = strip_tags(substr($_POST['t_cname'],0,32));
$t_phone = strip_tags(substr($_POST['t_phone'],0,32));
$t_description = strip_tags(substr($_POST['t_description'],0,32));
$t_tags = strip_tags(substr($_POST['t_tags'],0,32));


$results = mysql_query("INSERT INTO talents (id, t_username, t_password, t_fname, t_lname, t_cname, t_phone, t_description, t_tags, t_approved, t_dateofreg)
VALUES ('', '$t_username', '$t_password', '$t_fname', '$t_lname', '$t_cname', '$t_phone', '$t_description', '$t_tags', 'N', NOW() )"); // store date by NOW() // date int(8)

if($results) { echo "Successfully Added"; } else { die('Invalid query: '.mysql_error()); }

?>
```

if you needed the SQL query I could provide that.

Comment: you should provide the code in `connect.php` too since this is a connect to the database problem, not a failed query...

Comment: @MichalPlško it has my host name, username of database, password, and database name. You think it is necessary to post the codes of it as well?

Comment: do not expose the passwords of course :) `xxx` them out before posting.... there is no connect call to the database in the code you posted here, so either it is in `connect.php` or you are missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your mysql.conf settings are wrong, your php is compiled to search for mysql.sock in the wrong path or your mysql server is just not running. From what I see in the code you have posted you're not connecting to the database at all? Do you have `mysql_connect(); mysql_select_db();` in the `connect.php` file?

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know that I need to add the mysql_connect(); to my added.php page and to the connect.php Thanks so much =)

Comment: that's not correct @Khalid - either add it to `connect.php` or to `added.php`, do not add it to both... `connect.php` is called from the script, if you add it to both files you end up with duplicit connect calls...

Comment: @MichalPlško Thanks again. I will added to the connect.php only =) appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

happened before. simply define the connection right before the php validation or use an absolute path. furthermore, you could create a DB con class in your session file(i assume you have one, otherwise include it in the connection and simply instantiate whenever you need a connection)

```
<?php $root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
inlcude($root./connect.php);//edit the path as needed.
?>
```

other than that, you should know never to use relative paths, as this is a very bad habit. Also, i wouldn't use mysql for that. Go for mysqli parametized queries. It's an effort to upgrade but it's well worth the trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Alex appreciate it =)